# SSRS - Cascading Parameter? Parameter value then shows two other parameters?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

Apologies if this is rather straight forward.  I'm very new to SRSS and looked across for a solution but unfortunately at a point where I don't know how to proceed.

My report has 1 parameter at present (Choice a Yes/No option - which is also set in the where clause of the dataset = Where Choice = @choice....

The issue I'm having is if Choice is Yes by user, I want it then to show two date parameters of Month and Year, then require user to select these and then view report.  I've come across Cascading Parameters but correct me if I'm wrong this is related to the first parameter in this case Choice.  However, the yes or no is a derivation from a case statement it has nothing to do with the date and they are not related from a database point of view.  So not sure how I can get this to work.  Do I need to add an expression?

- I need two parameters showing when Choice = Yes
- I then need to know how to add this to the dataset (if only yes has been selected).

Sorry once again this might be straight forward, but I'm been trying for a couple of days with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Month and Year are parameters? And they are different in some way relating to the choice yes no?

Comment: Yes different as in no relation to the first parameter f choice but then would restrict current dataset to a number of records

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot conditionally hide parameters, so all 3 will need to be visible from the start. However, you can control how they behave to get better functionality.

I would suggest adding a dataset to the report that provides a list of years. This dataset would be used to populate the Available Values for the Year parameter. You can have the query here check the Choice parameter and if it's set to "No", then the query simply returns "Not Applicable". So the dropdown for year just has that one option as is essentially disabled. Repeat the same steps for the Month parameter and dataset.

You will also need to make sure the main dataset will handle these values. So the `WHERE` clause might look something like this:

```
WHERE (Year = @Year and Month = @Month) or @Year = 'Not Applicable'
```